# make jquery autocomplete also be controlled by arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm creating a website to start to learn coding and am making an search website with a search autocomplete. The script is [here](http://papermashup.com/jquery-php-ajax-autosuggest/).

This works great ( it really is a great and easy script for a jquery and coding beginner!)
but when the suggestions pop up, I'd like to be able to control them by moving up/down on my keyboard like Google's. How can I achieve this ( I know just the barest of bare bones about jquery :)

Super thanks for all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe consider using the autocomplete of jQuerys own jQuery-UI library:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

It has keyboard controls per default.

You could use your PHP script from the solution you posted, if you modify it like this:

```
$db = new mysqli('DB_HOST', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE_NAME');
//create array to store results
$results = array();

if ($db) {
  if (isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
    $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);
    if (strlen($queryString) > 0) {
      $query = $db->query("SELECT country FROM countries WHERE country LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");
      if ($query) {
        while ($result = $query->fetch_object()) {
          //add results to array
          $results[] = $result->country;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
//echo result array as JSON
echo json_encode($results);
```

see http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote for more details